# a fast algorithm to compute matrix multiplication

Tags: c++, arrays, matrix, multiplication

In the middle of a c++ code, eclipse, I need to compute the multiply of matrices A and B, with the size of 2400*3600 (so the dimensions are not the same). The matrices are stored in float two dimensional arrays.They are not sparse, no limitations.

Each multiply takes so long (several minutes), and I seriously need to reduce it, because I have a loop which repeats 50 million times. and each time a new A and B should be multiplied.
Any sort of recommendation is welcomed to reduce the time complexity. (even changing the structure of storing the data, if you think that might help). For example, what if I store the data into one dimensional arrays? Or using vectors instead of arrays?

In one particular case, the first column is always 1, and the values are either 1, -1, or zero. Any idea for this case?
In other cases, the values can be any thing.
** one of these multiplications is X multiplied by its transposed. Is there any recommendation on this specific one?

Comment: The naive algorithm for general matrix multiplication in O(n^3), but there are ways to get that down to O(n^(2.7ish)). This is just a **very big** computation if you'd can't reduce the work some before you begin. If the large number arises from a consistent set of transformation maybe you can do one per row and find the *deltas*. Or *something*.

Comment: Are your matrices mostly zeros? If so, then perhaps you can find a multiplication algorithm that operates on sparse matrices. A sparse matrix is essentially a `(i,j)->value` map.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I wouldn't fool around trying to write my own: Google for LAPACK or BLAS, two time-tested packages for numerical computing, both optimized to the Nth degree. Both have C APIs you can use.

Comment: +1: both libraries are not only using optimized algorithms, they are also using optimized implementations relying on SSE instructions.

Answer (score 9):

It will definitely help to store your second matrix transposed, so that columns match up with cache lines instead of rows.  The difference in access time between L2 cache and main memory is a factor of 10 or so.

Comment: Although seems quite obvious, I did not get what you mean. Could you explain a bit more? What if I really want to multiply A to its transpose?

Comment: @Pegah: If you look at the matrix multiply algorithm, you will find that the inner loop looks something like: `sum = 0; for( int k = 0; k < n; ++k ) sum += a[i][k] * b[k][j]; c[i][j] = sum;`.  Successive iterations access `a[i][0]`, `a[i][1]`, `a[i][2]`, which is fine because they're stored next to each other in memory, so the cache can read a big chunk from main memory at a time.  But you also access `b[0][j]`, `b[1][j]`, `b[2][j]`, which has very poor locality, and the cache has to perform many separate transfers from main memory, which is very wasteful.

Answer (score 2):

You might give [Eigen](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/index.php?title=Main_Page) a try.

Answer (score 1):

If you're talking about millions of multiplications, the first thing I'd do is turn to something like CUDA or DirectCompute to off-load the work to the GPU, which is way better suited to this kind of stuff. That's what MATLAB did, even if the GPU acceleration is optional.

There are a myriad of examples of GPU-accelerated matrix multiplication out there so your work shouldn't be too hard.

Comment: actually I need to do it in the middle of a c++ code, and its results is used by the rest of the code. so it is not an independent job. As far as I understood (I searched in web just now), GPU is a hardware based implementation and Directcompute is a separate application. Am I wrong? or can I still use GPU in my code?

Comment: I have no idea what you're talking about.. CUDA and DirectCompute are APIs that let you perform arithmetic on your GPU. Hardware based implementation what? In the middle of C++ code? As opposed to what?..

Comment: @Pegah Yes, your GPU is probably a hardware based implementation :)

Comment: @Pegah: GPU just means the processor chip on your video card.  It's very good at doing many of the same operation at once, not so good at complex branching.  A matrix multiply is a LOT of the same operation, so it runs very very fast on the GPU.  DirectCompute, CUDA, and OpenCL are libraries that allow a C++ program to issue instructions to your video card and move data back and forth.